# Difference beetwen "Html.TextAreaFor helper" and "Textarea" html tag

Tags: html, razor, textarea

I'am wondering is there any difference beetwen "Html.TextAreaFor helper" and "Textarea" html tag ?. I need add a javascript function "Onkeyup" on textarea, but when I'am using @Html.TextAreaFor helper like this for example:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.TekstStopka, new { id ="ObiektID", @class = "MyClass", maxlength = "300", onkeyup = "MyFunction('ObiektID', 'SecondObiektID')"})
```

in page source Razer is replacing " ' " into " &# 39; " and function won't work. But when i do this:

```
<textarea name="TekstStopka" id="TekstStopka" class = "MyClass" data-val="true" data-val-required="*" maxlength = "300" onkeyup="MyFunction('ObiektID', 'SecondObiektID')">@Model.TekstStopka</textarea>
```

It seems to work just fine. Can I do that, or is there any difference in page security ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always adviced to use htmlhelpers while working in MVC ,try this :

```
String onclick = String.Format("MyFunction({0},{1})", ObiektID,SecondObiektID);

@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.TekstStopka, new { id ="ObiektID", @class = "MyClass", maxlength = "300", onkeyup = "@onclick"})
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, but still the same problem :/

Comment: Works fine, i've made a little mistake in code ;). Thank You !

Answer (score 1):

The TextAreaFor makes it easy to bind to model data. It then translates into the html textarea tag. You will also get a compilation error if you change the name of your model properties but forget to change it in the view.

Passing arguments to a javascript event can be achieved in multiple ways:

---

**Example 1**

`@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Name, new {id = "123" onkeyup = "onkeyupevent('hello', id)" })`

**Example 2**

`@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Name, new {onkeyup = "onkeyupevent('hello', 123)" })`

**Example 3** (With model data)

`@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Name, new {id = Model.Id, onkeyup = "onkeyupevent('hello', id)" })`

**Example 4** (With model data)

`@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Name, new {id = Model.Id, onkeyup = "onkeyupevent('hello', " + Model.Id + ")" })`

---

Javascript example:

`function onkeyupevent(a1, a2) {
        alert(a1 + ' ' + a1);
    }`

Comment: I know, i can do that, but I need pass two parameters into javascript function. I cannot do that in that way, beacuse Razer is replacing ' into &# 39; and function won't work.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a couple of examples that worked for me. Maybe it can help you.